# passing map item into function always get the first item only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the small portion of the code where the problem lies.

> handleRating function

```
handleRating = (event, selectedValue, selectedRatingQuestion) => {
    let totalQuestionGenerated = [...this.state.totalQuestionGenerated];

    const newValue = selectedValue;
    let RatingQuestion = selectedRatingQuestion;

    const objectIndex = totalQuestionGenerated.findIndex(
      (question) =>
        question.textInputQuestionTitle ===
        RatingQuestion.textInputQuestionTitle
    );

    console.log("question title in selected question", RatingQuestion);
    console.log("object index", objectIndex);

    RatingQuestion.totalRating = newValue;
    totalQuestionGenerated[objectIndex] = RatingQuestion;

    this.setState({ totalQuestionGenerated });
  };
```

> Rendering the content

```
              {totalQuestionGenerated.map((question, i) =>
                question.questionType === "Rating" ? (
                  <React.Fragment key={`${question.questionType}${i}`}>
                    <FormLabel component="legend">
                      {question.textInputQuestionTitle}
                    </FormLabel>
                    <Rating
                      name="simple-controlled"
                      value={question.totalRating}
                      size="large"
                      onChange={(event, newValue) =>
                        this.handleRating(event, newValue, question)
                      }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                  </React.Fragment>
                ) : /*other code*/ }
```

`Rating` component is imported from material-ui

First, the totalQuestionGenerated is an array which consists of multiple question object. The problem is that when I pass the `question` item in the `map` function to the `OnChange` props in `Rating` component, it seems that I will only get the first question object no matter which question I clicked on. Therefore, the only rating question that can change its value is only the first question since the `selectedRatingQquestion` is always the first question for all cases.

> Console log from handleRating for all cases

question title in selected question > Object {/*first question attributes*/} 
object index > 0

> This is what happen when I clicked on the other question apart from first question

[image]

after that, only the first question will be modified.

[image]

Comment: try binding `value` prop to the state i.e. `this.state.totalQuestionGenerated[i].totalRating`

Comment: it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

If the first question is selected, the index should be 0, but in your console.log, it is > 0.
Have a check with your totalQuestionGenerated array.

Comment: the problem is that when i click at second or third question etc, it still print 0

Comment: and the object in the console log is the first question too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using findIndex do everything in forEach

```
  handleRating = (event, selectedValue, selectedRatingQuestion) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let totalQuestionGenerated = [...this.state.totalQuestionGenerated];

    let newValue = selectedValue;
    let RatingQuestion = selectedRatingQuestion;

    totalQuestionGenerated.forEach((question, index) => {
      if (
        question.textInputQuestionTitle ===
        RatingQuestion.textInputQuestionTitle
      ) {
        RatingQuestion.totalRating = newValue;
        totalQuestionGenerated[index] = RatingQuestion;

        this.setState({ totalQuestionGenerated:totalQuestionGenerated });
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: still does not solve the problem. The main issue is that the `selectedRatingQuestion` passed into this function will always be the first question, so i think the content of the handleRating function doesn't affect much.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution , each `Rating` component should have unique name, hence change the `name` props in `Rating` component to probably `Rate${i}` instead of `simple-controlled`.